# Filldown makes my formula disappear Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Looking to fill a variable range here. I can fill my formula to the right but when I want to fil it down, the formula disappears. I have also attached a picture and Column A starts with "Fund Name". Hope somebody can help me here thank you!! The link to the table is here. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ZVH.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ZVH.png

```
Sub Six_Continue()
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim lrow As Range
Dim Lastcol As Long
Dim lcol As Range

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set lrow = Range("C5:C" & Lastrow)

Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set lcol = Range("C3", Cells(3, Lastcol))


Range("C5").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(DataTable[[Period]:[Period]],SMALL(IF(DataTable[[LP ID]:[LP ID]]=C$2,IF(DataTable[[Fund ID]:[Fund ID]]=$B5,ROW(DataTable[[Fund ID]:[Fund ID]])-ROW(DataTable[[Fund ID]:[Fund ID]]))),1)),"" "")"
Range("C5", lcol.Offset(2)).FillRight
Range("C5", lcol.Offset(2)).FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `lrow` for? Because you set the range for it and never used it again.

Comment: Because there are spaces in between the table, lrow was initially set to find the rows that my formula would occupy. If I were to insert my formula into it, only Column C5 will have all the formulas but in the place that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below worked for me (with a much simplified array formula).

```
Sub Six_Continue()
    ' 25 Jan 2018

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastClm As Long

    With ActiveSheet                ' better specify by name
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastClm = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Cells(5, 3).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(DataTable[[Period]:[Period]],SMALL(IF(DataTable[[LP ID]:[LP ID]]=C$2,IF(DataTable[[Fund ID]:[Fund ID]]=$B5,ROW(DataTable[[Fund ID]:[Fund ID]])-ROW(DataTable[[Fund ID]:[Fund ID]]))),1)),"" "")"
'        .Cells(5, 3).FormulaArray = "= $a1 * $k1:$k5 * C$1"
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(5, 3), .Cells(5, LastClm))
        Rng.FillRight
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(5, 3), .Cells(LastRow, LastClm))
        Rng.FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this. The issue was that the formula does not become dynamic; It all returns the same result as Cell C5.

Comment: I tried filling across first, then the entire row down. Please try the revised code with your own formula.